# height 100% not extending the background color all the way

Tags: html, css, height, background-color

I have a content wrapper that I set height 100% but the problem is the background color does not fully extend across all of content. I've attached images and my code, any help would be great thanks!  The obvious white space after my wrapper: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnCkY.jpg

HTML (the part that does not work is the `div outerColor`):

```
<p id="dimensions"></p>
<div id="windpageTitle">

    <div class="headerContent">

        <nav>

            <ul class="navDown"> 
                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#windSubtitleSavings">Save</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#windSubtitleLocation">Locations</a></li>  
                <li><a href="#windSubtitleStart">Activate</a></li>     
            </ul>

            <a href="#" class="subMenuIcon"><p class="menu"></p></a>

        </nav>

        <h1 class="pageTitleText">Wind.</h1>

        <div class="pageNav">

            <ul class="navLink">

                <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#savingsSub">Savings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#locationSub">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="#SubtitleStart">Start</a></li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="outerColor">

    <div class="innerContent">

        <div id="savingsSub">

            <p class="graph"><img src="../images/graph.png" width="500px" height="500px" /></p>
            <p class="savingsText">Text here</p>

       </div>

       <div id="locationSub">

            <p class="map"><img src="../images/mapWind.png" width="500px" height="257px" /></p>
            <p class="locationText">TEXT HERE</p>

        </div>



    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#windpageTitle {
    background-color: #fff;
    width:100%;
    height:170px;
}

#outerColor {
    background-color:#666;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.innerContent {
    position:relative;
    width:90%;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#savingsSub {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    padding-top:40px;
    width:1300px;
    float: left;
}

.savingsText {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:right;
    padding-right:30px;
    padding-top:125px;
    width:700px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:25px;

}

#locationSub {
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    padding-top:55px;
    width:1600px;
    float: right;
}

.locationText {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    padding-left:350px;
    padding-top:55px;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:25px;
}

.graph {
    float:left;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

.map {
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your css, otherwise we won't be able to help without guessing.

Comment: added some more css sorry!

Comment: Should #outerColor be in .headerContent? 'cause in the html you posted the number opening/closing div tags doesn't match

Comment: @JonasGrumann I don't think so they are two separate "blocks" one the page

Comment: ok, but fix the divs in the code you provided

Comment: whoops the divs match up in my code just forgot to copy and paste the top part of a div to stack overflow sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Please add all HTML that is positioned within the  elements and all CSS. Now it's impossible to solve!